# How to save parent entity first with reference to child where child is not persisted yet (Objectify)?

Tags: java, google-cloud-datastore, objectify

Is there a way to create the reference of the child in a method but persist the child entity in a different method?

Right now, I am creating the reference first and then persisting the child in the same method. Only after this is being done, the parent is persisted. If DatastoreTimeoutException, ConcurrentModificationException, or DatastoreFailureException occurs during saving parent entity, I am left with child entity persisted in datastore which is of no use.

```
@Entity
@Index
public class parentEntity
    {

@Id
private String uniqueIdentifier;
private String name = new String();
@Load
private LinkedList <Ref <childEntity>> refToChild = new LinkedList <Ref <childEntity>>();

          }

@Entity
@Index
public class childEntity
    {

@Id
private String uniqueIdentifier;
private String address = new String();
@Load
@Parent
public Ref <parentEntity> refToParent;

          }
```

```
This method first creates the reference parent has with child and then persists the entity(child)
```

```
public static void createRefAndSaveChildEntity()
{
   Ref.create( key ) ;//creates the reference with child
   ofy().save().entity( childEntity ).now(); 
}
```

I want to persist the child only after the parent(with reference to child) is being persisted.

Comment: why would you want to link to an object that doesn't exist yet? what if there's a problem persisting the child entity?

Comment: Given that you are using a parent-child relationship, you should be able to use an ancestor query to retrieve the children instead of keeping an explicit reference to the child entities in the parent entity.

Comment: @Stultuske yeah, coming to think of it, a problem could arise when persisting the child.

Comment: @JimMorrison, yeah for querying i could, but how to do while saving?

Comment: What I was saying is that you don't need to keep an explicit reference because you have an implicit reference through ancestor queries.